# Set Value and Display Name from Query String if Exists - ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to set itemMasterid and Display Value for Autocomplete field but when used useSearchParam or useQueryState code is going into infinite loop and lot of same API calls are being done and then some error like below popups up.

```
Unexpected Application Error!
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

so if anyone could help me figure out what would be the proper way to add depenedies maybe in the useEffect such that it doesn't go into infinite loop.

Actual working Source Code

```
import { Autocomplete, Box, Button, CircularProgress, Grid, Popover, Stack, TextField } from '@mui/material'
import { format } from 'date-fns'
import { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { DateRange } from 'react-date-range'
import { useTitle } from '@react-hooks-library/core'

import LedgerTableCellComponent from '@/components/ledger/ledger-table-cell-component'
import { PageHeader } from '@/components/page-header'
import PaginatedDatatable from '@/components/paginated-datatable'
import { useLedgerStore } from '@/global/state/ledger-state'
import { useSearchItemMaster } from '@/hooks/item-master/useSearchItemMaster'
import { useGetLedger } from '@/hooks/ledger/useGetLedger'

export const Ledger = (props) => {
  useTitle(`${props.title} - ${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME}`)
  const currentPage = useLedgerStore((state) => state.currentPage)
  const setCurrentPage = useLedgerStore((state) => state.setCurrentPage)
  const pageSize = useLedgerStore((state) => state.pageSize)
  const setPageSize = useLedgerStore((state) => state.setPageSize)

  const { data, isLoading, isFetching, isRefetching, refetch } = useGetLedger()
  const loading = isLoading || isFetching || isRefetching

  const columns = [
    { name: 'ledgerId', title: 'ID' },
    { name: 'direction', title: 'Direction' },
    { name: 'oldQuantity', title: 'Old Quantity' },
    { name: 'quantity', title: 'Quantity' },
    { name: 'newQuantity', title: 'New Quantity' },
    { name: 'itemMasterName', title: 'Item Master Name' },
    { name: 'remark', title: 'Remark' },
    { name: 'createdBy', title: 'Created By' },
    { name: 'createdTime', title: 'Created Time' },
    { name: 'actions', title: 'Actions' },
  ]

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Grid container columns={12} spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <PageHeader refetch={refetch} isLoading={loading} title='Ledger' subtitle='Ledger of all items' />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Grid container columns={12} spacing={2} justifyContent='end'>
            <Grid item xl={3} lg={3} md={6} sm={12} xs={12}></Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid container item spacing={2} alignItems='center' xs={12}>
          <Grid item xs={9}>
            <SearchItemMaster />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={3}>
            <SelectDateRange />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <PaginatedDatatable
            columns={columns}
            rows={data.ledgers}
            pageSize={pageSize}
            loading={loading}
            currentPage={currentPage}
            setPageSize={setPageSize}
            totalCount={data.totalCount}
            setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}
            cellComponent={LedgerTableCellComponent}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

const SearchItemMaster = () => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([])

  const { mutateAsync, isLoading } = useSearchItemMaster()

  const handleInputChange = async (event, value, reason) => {
    await mutateAsync(
      { search: value },
      {
        onSuccess: (data, variables, context) => {
          setOptions(data)
        },
      }
    )
  }

  const itemMaster = useLedgerStore((state) => state.itemMaster)
  const setItemMaster = useLedgerStore((state) => state.setItemMaster)

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      setOptions([])
      setItemMaster(null)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      autoComplete
      id='search-item-master'
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.display}
      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.itemMasterId === value.itemMasterId}
      onInputChange={handleInputChange}
      value={itemMaster}
      onChange={(event, value) => setItemMaster(value)}
      renderInput={(params) => {
        return (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label='Search item master'
            InputProps={{
              ...params.InputProps,
              endAdornment: (
                <Fragment>
                  {isLoading ? <CircularProgress color='inherit' size={20} /> : null}
                  {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                </Fragment>
              ),
            }}
          />
        )
      }}
    />
  )
}

const SelectDateRange = () => {
  const state = useLedgerStore((state) => state.dateRange)
  const setState = useLedgerStore((state) => state.setDateRange)

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null)

  const handleClick = (event) => setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)
  const handleClose = () => setAnchorEl(null)

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl)
  const id = open ? 'date-range-popover' : undefined

  const handleReset = () => {
    setState([
      {
        startDate: null,
        endDate: null,
        key: 'selection',
      },
    ])
    handleClose()
  }

  const buttonLabel =
    state[0].startDate && state[0].endDate
      ? `${format(state[0].startDate, 'dd/MM/yy')} to ${format(state[0].endDate, 'dd/MM/yy')}`
      : 'Select date range'

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Button fullWidth aria-describedby={id} variant='contained' onClick={handleClick}>
        {buttonLabel}
      </Button>
      <Popover id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl} onClose={handleClose}>
        <Stack>
          <DateRange
            editableDateInputs={true}
            onChange={(item) => setState([item.selection])}
            moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
            ranges={state}
            color='#5d3fb3'
            direction='horizontal'
            rangeColors={['#5d3fb3', '#3ecf8e', '#fed14c']}
          />
          <Box p={2}>
            <Button fullWidth onClick={handleReset}>
              Reset date range
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Stack>
      </Popover>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```